# svn : filter only remotely modified files in `svn st -u`

Tags: svn, remote, status

When performing a subversion status update

`svn st -u`

All changes both remote and local are displayed. Is there a way to filter this list to show only remotely modified files?

(without using `awk`, `sed` or the like)

Answer (score 2):

Almost:

```
svn diff --summarize -rCOMMITTED:HEAD
```

`--summarize` causes svn diff to emit status-style output.

However, this will not compare each file to the repository as `svn status -u` does, but rather compare the revision which the current directory is at to HEAD. Therefore if you have a mixed-revision working copy, such as if you committed but did not update, this will report your committed files as modified.

Comment: +1 @Kevin : Unfortunately I need to do this because I **have** a mixed-revision working copy. Thanks for the answer - I'm sure it will come in useful somewhere else!

Comment: If you want a thoroughly engineered solution, I suggest `svn status -u --xml | xsltproc my-filter.xslt`.